# Hadoop exception while starting

Tags: macos, hadoop, homebrew, hadoop3

Exception while running

```
sudo sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

> /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh:
>   line 398: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh:
>   line 398:`  done < <(for text in "${input[@]}"; do'
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 70: hadoop_deprecate_envvar: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 87: hadoop_bootstrap: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 104: hadoop_parse_args: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 105: shift: : numeric argument required
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 244: hadoop_need_reexec: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 252: hadoop_verify_user_perm: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 213:
>   hadoop_validate_classname: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/hdfs: line 214:
>   hadoop_exit_with_usage: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 263: hadoop_add_client_opts: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 270: hadoop_subcommand_opts: command not found
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.0/libexec/bin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh:
>   line 273: hadoop_generic_java_subcmd_handler: command not found
>   WARNING: HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER has been replaced by
>   HDFS_DATANODE_SECURE_USER. Using value of HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER

Comment: Try downloading Hadoop from official website, not Homebrew

Comment: I followed below link, it is working now https://dtflaneur.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-el-capitan/